# Cannot display selected date using Bootstrap-datepicker-rails as "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

I am attempting to put the bootstrap-datepicker on date input fields in my application.   After the date is selected from the calendar, I want the date to display as 'dd/mm/yyyy'.  The  Dates are saved in the table (sqlite) in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

I have done the following:

In the application.js file, I have:

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require jquery-ui
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require bootstrap-datepicker
   //= require_tree .
```

In the application.html.erb file, I have:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

In the custom.css.scss, I have:

```
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";
```

In the related .js file, I have:

```
   $(document).on("focus", "[data-behaviour~='datepicker']", function(e){
   $(this).datepicker({"format": "dd-mm-yy", "weekStart": 1, autoclose": true, "language": 'en-GB'})});
```

I have also tried this code in the application.js file - with no luck.

In the related form, I have:

```
    <a> Start Date/time: </a>
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', size:10 %>
```

Result: I get a calendar from which I can select a date, but the date shows up in the default format of "mm/dd/yyyy".

Other tries:   I have put the script in the form, but that has also not worked.

Any help will be immensely appreciated.

Thanking you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this kind of situation where i want one date format to display date in text field and another format to save date.

so my work around is as follows

Declare different fields to accept date and to save date.
here my accept field is "**select_date**" and actual field is "**date**"

```
= text_field_tag :select_date, '', :class => "datepicker"
= hidden_field_tag("date", "", :id => "request_date")
```

and simple script helps me to save value in both fields.

```
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'DD MM d',
    altField: '#request_date',
    altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

so when you select value in calendar, it fills both fields in different format.

Comment: Thank you very much Chaitanya Saraf.  This is the only solution that worked for me though the other answers below look like they should work.    I also had to put the function in the form as a <script> because the previous form has a helper that, though I couldn't tell why, was overriding the .js file.

Comment: glad to hear that it works for you, thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set the date format as data attribute as,

```
<%= f.text_field :start_date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', size:10, 'data-date-format' => "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the date in  `'dd/mm/yyyy'` format by using [strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

```
<a> Start Date/time: </a>
<%= f.text_field :start_date, value: (f.object.start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") if f.object.start_date.present?), 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker', size:10 %>
```